# Equivalence of log linear and logistic regression for categorical variables

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, log-linear

This question is similar to

[Does every log-linear model have a perfectly equivalent logistic regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/54498/does-every-log-linear-model-have-a-perfectly-equivalent-logistic-regression)

but my problem is understanding the proof.Every proof is very similar to the one found on: http://teaching.sociology.ul.ie/SSS/lugano/node58.html. for a $n$ by $2$ contingency table
$$\log(\mu_{ij} ) = \lambda_0 + \lambda^A_i + \lambda^B_j + \lambda^{AB}_{ij}   $$
$$\log(\mu_{i1} ) - \log( \mu_{i0}) =logit(p) = (\lambda^B_1 - \lambda^B_2) +(\lambda^{AB}_{i1}-\lambda^{AB}_{i2} )$$

reparamitised to

$$logit(p)= \alpha+ \beta_i$$

This proves that log linear models have an equivalent logistic model. I'm convined this result is true from numericla result.

My problem with the proof is that the $\lambda$'s are estimated from a Poisson likelihood and the $\alpha$ and $\beta_i$ are estimated from a bernoulli/ binomial log likelihood. How is it that they're the same? Do we need to go a step further and show that the  $\alpha$ and $\beta_i$ found from the likelihood for logistic regression also maximise the likelihood for the log linear model?